# php mixing singleton with dependency injection

Tags: php, dependencies, singleton, mixing

I found myself in a situation where I'm not sure which way I should go. So far I'm using dependency injection where I pass PDO object to as a dependency.

This works quite fine, but now I need to have a Context class which would be for example holding the Info of current user. It could be something like this:

```
class Context
{
    private $Pdo;

    function __construct(PDO $Pdo) {
        $this->Pdo = $Pdo;
    }

    function CurrentUser(){
        if ($this->CurrentUser == null){
            // get user logic 
                        $this->CurrentUser = User;
        }
        return $this->CurrentUser;
    }
}
```

So each time I would like to get the current user I would need to do something like this:

```
$Context = new Context($Pdo);
$User = $Context->CurrentUser();
```

I would like to be able to use this anywhere in project, but the PDO is not passed to each method there is.

I could make a singleton class for getting the PDO object anywhere I need and use that in my Context class. Would this be a good aproach? Or would a factory design be better?

Up until now I used global in such cases, but I would probably want to avoid there as the project grows rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

> I could make a singleton class for getting the PDO object anywhere I
>   need and use that in my Context class. Would this be a good aproach?
>   Or would a factory design be better?

Well, Singleton and Factory are not really the same thing, and your particular needs should dictate the solution.

Here is a short summary of a [more in-depth post](http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.com/2013/04/difference-between-singleton-and.html):

The Singleton pattern restricts the instantiation of a class to a single object. This provides a single point of access across the entire application, and ensure that you are always dealing with the same object.

The Factory pattern provides a new instance of the object whenever it is called. This may or may not be the same instance. Essentially the factory defines an interface for creating objects.

So, your needs will determine which pattern is better for your application. If you want a single instance of an object, go with a singleton.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, however I know how the design patterns work, I was more interested of which approach would be best in this particular case of having Context class which would be available anywhere, anytime.. :) Would that be considered as a particular bad practise? I cannot seem to figure out a better way..

Comment: @user3370402 - If you want to have a single instance of your PDO object available everywhere, the Singleton pattern would be fine. If you want to try an alternative, look into using the Registry pattern... but I thing the Simpleton will be much easier to implement/understand. I have mixed feelings about Singletons, but they are widely used and *very easy* to implement, so if it solves your problem, go for it.